# Choosing the right diode for my H-bridge?

Tags: diodes, dc-motor, h-bridge, flyback

I'm making a H-bridge for a 12V DC-motor. I have to choose a flyback diode but I have a hard time determining the motor's back EMF voltage. I'm assuming this voltage won't be more than double the supply voltage of 12.6V. The maximum current through the motor is 6A.
I'm also assuming that my transistor Q5 should be on when changing the direction of the motor leaving a path for the current made from the back EMF to flow in. Is this correct?

I was also wondering if there is a need of some sort of decoupling when a high current is rushing to V_Batt?

[image]

Comment: Why switching with Q5 when you have already paid for and accepted the losses of Q1 and Q2?

Comment: @winny using Q5 overcomes shoot-through if done correctly... However, it's a bit like the old song; there was an old woman who swallowed a fly... I don't know if you have that in Sweden?

Comment: why have you drawn an inductor parallel with the motor?

Comment: @winny the reason for this is, that I only have one PWM available to control the motor speed. Another thing is that I don't need to time anything as the two transistors can't be on at the same time eliminating shoot-through as Andy aka said.

Comment: @Jasen this is because I'm using a shunt-wound motor. Here the armature and field coils are in parallel as shown in my diagram.

Comment: @Andyaka can you explain in detail why this is a bad idea?

Comment: if it's a shunt-wound motor what is the purpose of the H bridge?

Comment: @Jasen just found out it isn't. I was wrong it is a DC series motor.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad idea just inefficient in that you have three MSOFETs in series with the motor - bigger losses.

Comment: @Andyaka is there another good way of designing the h-bridge sparing the extra mosfet if you only have access to one PWM signal and need to control motor speed?

Comment: for series or parallel. you need to connect the stator and the brushes separately if you want to be able to reverse the motor using the h bridge.

Comment: Thank you for that Jasen!

Comment: Q5 doesn't need to be on for a back EMF current path: There's the body diode. Then again, you could connect D2&D4 to ground instead of Q5. How does knowing fly-back voltage of the motor's inductance or its back-EMF voltage help selecting the diodes?

Comment: The transistor Q5 was used because only one pwm signal was available to drive the h-bridge. Knowing the back-EMF voltage I could determine the power dissipated in the diodes.

Answer (score 1):

typical back EMF is slightly less than the supply voltage.

worst case is slightly more if there an external force driving the motor.

Answer (score 1):

External diodes are not necessary as the MOSFETs include body diodes, intrinsically (notice in the symbol, the triangle pointing at/away from the line segment (channel) denoting a diode junction).